# Pending Order Hold Stock not working in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, payment-method

I've already setup Hold Stock (minustes) in here WooCommerce > Settings > Inventory > Hold Stock (minutes). But my pending order is not cancel.

I also tried [this method](https://github.com/crazyscience/woocommerce/commit/9898aee867dbab56f522e63cd7bcf2a61a1fd410) but I can't cancel my pending order.

How can i solve it ?

My wordpress version is 4.0.1 & WooCommerce version is 2.1.12

Comment: this is not the woocomerce support forum

Comment: Ask here https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce